# Tab bar with custom indicator on swiping changes with weird UI rendering

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The tab bar with a custom tab indicator created by changing the tabs container decoration as shown below. Its works nicely when changing the tabs with tap on the tab bar. But when changing the tabs using swipe left/ right action manually slowly, I could see the tab bar changing to new decoration with a weird UI rendering.
[image]

```
tabBar() => TabBar(
        isScrollable: false,
        controller: tabController,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
            color: myAccentColor, borderRadius:12),
        tabs: tabs(),
      );
```

```
tabs() => [
        Container(
            height: tabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: tabIndex == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Color(0xffF7F7F7),
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              "Trending",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(
                  color:
                      tabIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : V2Colors.darkColor292929),
            ))),
        Container(
            height: tabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: tabIndex == 1 ? Colors.transparent : Color(0xffF7F7F7),
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              "My Feed",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(
                  color:
                      tabIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : V2Colors.darkColor292929),
            ))),
        Container(
            height: tabHeight,
            color: tabIndex == 2 ? Colors.transparent : Color(0xffF7F7F7),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              "My Topics",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(
                  color:
                      tabIndex == 2 ? Colors.white : V2Colors.darkColor292929),
            ))),
      ];
```

Any direction towards a better approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `tabs()` method, set all the `Tabs` color as Transparent (Your `Containers`).

Instead of this

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: tabIndex == 1 ? Colors.transparent : Color(0xffF7F7F7),
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)),
              ),
            ),
```

Use

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(
                      width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)),
                ),
              ),
```

> Note: Try to make a CustomWidgets wherever possible. For examples You
> Items in the `tabs()` method can be a Custom Widget. For ex:
> `CustomTabWidget`